# CUDA Threads execution order

Tags: cuda

> In CUDA when we talk about parallel threads executing the same code is there any order to their execution?

### For-example:

If, I have 4 threads,for a 1D array of 4 elements.All four threads perfom some operation on some index of the array.
Will thread 4 always execute after thread 3 or there is no specific order in the execution?

Thank you!

Comment: Read your question and example again. How can thread 4 be executed after thread 3 if they are excecuted parallel and smaller then the warpsize. The question could be valid if you compare the warp execution order or block execution. But neither is guaranteed.

Comment: I was confused about parallel threads determining the value of a variable common to all of them,hence my question related to their order of execution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, there are no order in threads execution. It's wrong to rely on the order of threads designing your algorithm.

Comment: So, supposedly if I have a 'counter' whose value determines the output index and is global to all the threads who also change its value,then this approach would naturally be faulty and unpredictable as I won't be knowing which thread changes the value of the counter first.Right?

Comment: that is correct. What you would need to do to make that "counter" return an accurate figure is to have each thread update a local counter, store those in a separate array and then add up the elements of the array to get the final figure. That is called "reduction" and can also be done in parallel.

Comment: Also You can use atomic operations. They are not to slowly like for early architectures was. By the way you can determine the first change programmatically if you want to track who was the first.

Comment: @marina.k Any hacked serialization/synchronization is against the gpu (SIMD) programming paradigm and CUDA architecture. And I doubt a high performance can be reached compared to a rewritten optimized algorithm. I never saw any example where such synchronisation was necessary on kernel level and also faster and the algorithm could not be changed.

Comment: @djmj: I totally agree. My own opinion is If you work with GPU you must accept it's rules=) But solution for this question is possible.

Comment: @marina.k I just wanted to mention it for others even I thought you were aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no deterministic order for threads' execution and if you need a specific order then you should be programming it sequentially instead of using a parallel execution model.

There is *something* that can be said about thread execution, though. In CUDA's execution model, threads are grouped in "warps". Depending on the compute capability of the underlying device, each warp (or half-warp) is executed simultaneously - literally at the same time. The execution proceeds until the code locks due to waiting for memory transference and another warp (or half-warp) is scheduled to run.

The documentation, though, is very specific about what assumptions you can make on the matter: the best execution barrier you have is a kernel call ending.